# Age differences

Tags: discussion, new-users, age

I realize that Stack Exchange sites accommodate a variety of people, whether they are professional or enthusiast contributors, whether they are 13 or >60.

But does SE have encouragement strategies specifically for younger contributors?

(IE: teaching these new users how to contribute to SE sites, from their age perspective.)

Comment: My question was aimed towards educating younger users rather than the legal obligations of the elder SE users/moderators. Editing shall be required :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the official police a community manager can tell you more, but take a look at the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name). It goes from [Academics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), to [Parents and grandparents](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) and even [young people](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/) (just a joke, no offense).

SE is for everyone. Not a specific culture, age, faith, or anything else. There is no specific policy to allow or encourage a specific age group.

As an active member on SO I see a broad variety of people. Usually we need to educate new people, but that doesn't strictly relate to age, more to the way they are used to interact. I don't think we have to educate different ages differently based on my experience.

Comment: Not me, but the answer doesn't give much information. Might be better only as a comment.

Comment: On what does it need more info? The question is `does SE have encouragement strategies specifically for younger contributors`. The answer is `no`. The proof is in the list of sites.

Comment: Dunno, I find it on the gray zone - fair answer, not great and not bad - others have different opinions.

Comment: so to conclude, SE sites are fully inclusive, regardless of age, so guidelines are not required since the Q/A format rules are easily understood by everyone?

Comment: @edition Not everyone, no. But not specific groups of people that can reasonably be identified and helped.